# Paperclip - Using custom watermark with dynamic path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, watermark

I'm trying to create a custom path using this:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
    :processors => [:watermark],
    :styles => lambda { |attachment| {
        :medium => {
            :geometry       => "300x300>",
            :watermark_path => Customer.find(attachment.instance.customer_id).signature.path
        },
        :thumb => "100x100>",
    }
}
```

This is working fine with `Customer.find(attachment.instance.customer_id).signature.path` with a static path to image, but in this case it is throwing an exception

```
Paperclip::Errors::InfiniteInterpolationError in  Api::Ipad::V1::ImagesController#create
```

Can anyone tell how to ignore this exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually that error comes from not explicity defining the :url and :path options for the attachment, might try setting those options and see if the interpolation error goes away.